# MySQL system table missing after install

Tags: mysql, installation

I just installed mysql 5.6.13 and ran `mysql_secure_installation` to setup my password. I am able to login to the DB as root with my new password but I'm not seeing the 'mysql' system DB. Have I missed a step somewhere?

```
mysql> show grants;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*...' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed all instances of MySQL via terminal using the commands:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/MySQL*
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*
```

Then reinstalled using this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5a-Dn7GGVc

And all is working correctly now.